# Using Aliases inside Admin Panel for fields

Tags: admin

I was wondering if it was possible to use an alias inside a field in the Admin panel. For example, I have a global section called "Navigation" which contains a matrix called "Links". This matrix allows the client to create links for their navigation bar. Inside each matrix block, is a field called "Link Url" where the client can put in a link.

Right now the client is hardcoding urls for the production site, so my links don't work on my dev environment. I would like to rectify this, with some type of elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach would be to use the `UrlHelper` [class](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-urlhelper.html) it has a function [UrlHelper::url()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-urlhelper.html#method-url) that is available in Twig and will return the correct URL for a certain path. So you could ask your client to not insert the entire URL, only the path -> instead of `example.com/entries` -> `entries` or you can include a custom Twig function/behavior that strips the domain before you use the `{{ url('entries') }}` function.

Anyway: to be honest I would create a different approach in the first place. Creating static URLs in a text field is usually not a good thing. I'm always a fan of the

> protect clients against themselves

philosophy so you may want to consider to create a custom field type with autosuggestion or something. SEO wise it could be a bad idea if you clients are able to insert whatever they want and you output too many dead links. Maybe a Relation field could be something for you?

Comment: So I actually went with your suggestion of just having the client put in the slug of the url. Inside my template I just append the siteUrl onto the front of it. It seems to work across three different languages.